# How to modify calendar event object popover's values in Odoo 13

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-13

[image: Image Link]

What is the box in blue border called? and how can I modify the fields in red borders? I want to programmatically modify those values.

Answer (score 1):

in Odoo 14 this popover is defined in `odoo/addons/web/static/src/xml/web_calendar.xml`

```xml
<t t-name="CalendarView.event.popover">
    <div class="o_cw_body">
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <li t-if="!widget.hideDate and widget.eventDate.date" class="list-group-item">
                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-calendar-o"/>
                <b class="text-capitalize" t-esc="widget.eventDate.date"/> <small t-if="widget.eventDate.duration"><b t-esc="_.str.sprintf('(%s)', widget.eventDate.duration)"/></small>
            </li>
            <li t-if="!widget.hideTime and widget.eventTime.time" class="list-group-item">
                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-clock-o"/>
                <b t-esc="widget.eventTime.time"/> <small t-if="widget.eventTime.duration"><b t-esc="_.str.sprintf('(%s)', widget.eventTime.duration)"/></small>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul t-if="widget.isEventDetailsVisible()" class="list-group list-group-flush o_cw_popover_fields_secondary"/>
        <div class="card-footer border-top">
            <a t-if="widget.isEventEditable()" href="#" class="btn btn-primary o_cw_popover_edit">Edit</a>
            <a t-if="widget.isEventDeletable()" href="#" class="btn btn-secondary o_cw_popover_delete ml-2">Delete</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</t>
```

The Widget in JavaScript is this one `odoo/addons/web/static/src/js/views/calendar/calendar_popover.js`

You can extend it to modify it's value or add other field, etc:

```js
var CalendarPopover = Widget.extend(WidgetAdapterMixin, StandaloneFieldManagerMixin, {
    template: 'CalendarView.event.popover',
    events: {
        'click .o_cw_popover_edit': '_onClickPopoverEdit',
        'click .o_cw_popover_delete': '_onClickPopoverDelete',
    },
    /**
     * @constructor
     * @param {Widget} parent
     * @param {Object} eventInfo
     */
    init: function (parent, eventInfo) {
        this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        StandaloneFieldManagerMixin.init.call(this);
        this.hideDate = eventInfo.hideDate;
        this.hideTime = eventInfo.hideTime;
        this.eventTime = eventInfo.eventTime;
        this.eventDate = eventInfo.eventDate;
        this.displayFields = eventInfo.displayFields;
        this.fields = eventInfo.fields;
        this.event = eventInfo.event;
        this.modelName = eventInfo.modelName;
        this._canDelete = eventInfo.canDelete;
    },
    //... rest of the class
```

Comment: isn't there any python code related to it using which I can modify the values in popover?